# Grouping by multiple columns and aggregating all values

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I am rather new to Power Bi and I have a question i can't find the answer to.

I want to import a table that have some label columns, with repeated items, and more than 15 data columns.

My desire result would be to group the label columns, so no repeated items, and aggregate the values of the remaining columns.

Is there a way to do that in PQ editor or DAX ?

I appreciate any help or direction you can give me!

A sample of the table (it's much bigger, with multiple values in the first three columns)

[Table Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8uSR.png)

Thanks a lot

Edit: From that sample, the output y I want is the following

[Output Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkHZA.png)

The thing is, there are many different values in the first columns, and i need to agreggate all the other values, keeping they column name (cause this info is already linked to other files).

Maybe the only way is to group by and add the columns, renaming them one by one?
I want to do this in a couple of files, so if you know of another way please let me know!

Comment: Please post the expected output based on the sample picture you provided. It is hard to understand what is the structure of the output you are after.

Answer (score 0):

In your query designer import your table. Then go to `Home > Group By` and group like you want it, the same goes for the aggregations and thats it.

If you just want to remove row duplicates, just group all columns which you dont want to aggregate and the rest can be aggregated like you want it.